# powershell that reads values from csv or json file and create registry keys if do not exist

Tags: json, powershell, csv, registry

I am trying to write a powershell script that creates registry keys and their values from a csv or json file containing the list of the registries .
did any one code such thing can help ? :)

Comment: Can we see what you've tried so far?(:

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Using `ConvertFrom-Json`, convert your JSON to a custom **PSCustomObject** object. Then iterate through the object properties and call `New-ItemProperty` to create the new registry entries with the appropriate values.

### PowerShell

```
$jsonFile = "<path to JSON file>"
$customObject = Get-Content $jsonFile | ConvertFrom-Json

$customObject.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
    [void](New-ItemProperty -LiteralPath $_.Value.path -Name $_.Value.name -Value $_.Value.value -PropertyType $_.Value.type -Force)
}
```

### JSON

```
{
    "reg1": {
        "path": "path1",
        "name": "name1",
        "value": "value1",
        "type": "type1"
    },
    "reg2": {
        "path": "path2",
        "name": "name2",
        "value": "value2",
        "type": "type2"
    },
    "reg3": {
        "path": "path3",
        "name": "name3",
        "value": "value3",
        "type": "type3"
    }
}
```

### Links

[ConvertFrom-Json (learn.microsoft.com)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-5.1)
[New-ItemProperty (learn.microsoft.com)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-itemproperty?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: can you take a look at the error below while running the powershell script please ? :)

Comment: ConvertFrom-Json : ConvertFrom-Json: Escape sequence was not recognized. (45): {
    "reg1": {
        "path": "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients",
        "name": "test",
        "value": "0000",
        "type": "REG_SZ"
    },
    "reg2": {
        "path": "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients",
        "name": "test2",
        "value": "value2",
        "type": "REG_SZ"
    },
    "reg3": {
        "path": "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients",
        "name": "name3",
        "value": "value3",
        "type": "REG_SZ"
    }
}

Comment: At line:2 char:41
+ $customObject = Get-Content $jsonFile | ConvertFrom-Json
+                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand

Comment: Your paths probably need _double_ backslashes since single backslashes are interpreted as escape characters. `"path": "Computer\\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Clients"`

Comment: im giving the right path but it is giving : New-ItemProperty : Cannot find path 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\test' because it does not exist. while it exists in registry :O

Comment: For the `-Path` parameter, try to access the PowerShell registry provider via the built-in **HKLM:** drive: `New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:SOFTWARE\Clients -Name ..."`

Comment: thanks so much for your help but im afraid this didnt work either ;( do you have any other suggestion i can try ?

Comment: Please edit your original question and add some snippets from both your JSON and PowerShell code so I can see how you have everything set up. It's hard to know how to help you further without more information.

Comment: Hello , i reposted the question with the code , can you take a look at it please ? :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68111583/how-to-add-a-registry-key-from-powershell-that-reads-content-from-json