# How to add or update registry keys?

Tags: json, powershell, registry

I have a Powershell script that reads content from JSON file and adds registry values. My script works well if the key in the registry exists. How can I make it to create the key if it doesn't exist, and then insert a value to it?

Powershell:

```
$jsonFile = "c:\temp\story\test2.json"
$customObject = Get-Content $jsonFile | ConvertFrom-Json

$customObject.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
    [void]( New-ItemProperty -LiteralPath $_.Value.path -Name $_.Value.name -Value $_.Value.value -PropertyType $_.Value.type -Force)
    }
```

Json:

```
{
    "reg1": {
        "path": "HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Clients\\test",
        "name": "test",
        "value": "0000",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "reg2": {
        "path": "HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Clients\\test",
        "name": "test2",
        "value": "111",
        "type": "String"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Test-Path` to test if the registry path exists or not.

```
Get-Content -Path 'c:\temp\story\test2.json' -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($reg in $_.PSObject.Properties.value) {
        if (!(Test-Path -Path $reg.path)) { $null = New-Item -Path $reg.path -Force }
        $null = New-ItemProperty -Path $reg.path -Name $reg.name -Value $reg.value -PropertyType $reg.type -Force
    }
}
```

Comment: @Haz Thanks for the nice feedback. BTW, Being new to the platform you may not know this, but it's customary to mark the question 'done' by accepting the answer. You can do that by clicking the large checkmark icon on the left of the answer, This will help others with a similar question finding it more easily.